# CoreData with NSPredicate and OR condition

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a question about *NSPredicate*.

I use this predicate to take all result with `status=="Compare"`

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription @"MyEntity"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [request setEntity:entity];

        NSPredicate *predicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@",@"Created"];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
```

but Now I would to take all result that status is equal to "`Created`" **OR** "`Readed`".
How I have to change my predicate?

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
  return [[evaluatedObject status] isEqualToString:@"Created"] || [[evaluatedObject status] isEqualToString:@"Readed"];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status IN %@",@[@"Created", @"Readed"]];
```